# Google Maps API v3 - IP-based Geolocation

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

Has anyone been able to get geo-location based on a person's IP to work using Google Maps API v3 JavaScript?

It seems to me that even the google provided example doesn't work.

http://gmaps-samples-v3.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/commonloader/clientlocation.html

**Question**:

1. Does this example work for anyone?
2. How do I get geolocation based on a person's IP to work using Google Maps API v3?

Answer (score 5):

**Q1:** It works from here, and probably from many other locations. However note that geolocation from IP addresses is not a very reliable science. You will be getting the location of your ISP, which can be quite far away, and in addition the IP-to-location databases aren't always up to date with the latest changes, so you might not have any data for a particular IP address -- which is probably what is happening in your case.

MaxMind, which offers a popular IP-to-location database published some statistics on its database:

- [GeoIP City Accuracy for Selected Countries](http://www.maxmind.com/app/city_accuracy)

**Q2:** The only way to get the geolocation from an IP address through the Google Maps API v3 is by using the same method used in the [example you provided](http://gmaps-samples-v3.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/commonloader/clientlocation.html). However if you find that any other geolocation database, like [MaxMind GeoLite City](http://www.maxmind.com/app/geolitecity), is more accurate for your country, you may want to do the geolocation from the IP Addresses yourself, instead of delegating it to Google Maps.

Comment: works from here as well. probably your (OP) location is not in the databases.

Comment: Works fine for me as well (City level).

Answer (score 3):

The web Google Maps API doesn't seem to offer an IP address geolocation service (the provided [example](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/geolocation) suggests using the W3C Geolocation standard, which typically requires an action from the user).

However! Google's [Maps Geolocation API](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geolocation/intro), typically used on mobile clients, *can* be used from the web and *does* return a latitude & longitude based on the requesting client's IP address.

Here's a quick jQuery example that demonstrates its use:

```
  $.ajax({
    url: 'https://www.googleapis.com/geolocation/v1/geolocate?key=YOUR-API-KEY',
    data: JSON.stringify({ "considerIp": "true" }),
    type: 'POST',
    contentType: 'application/json',
    success: function(data) {
      if(data.location) {
        alert(data.location.lat + ', ' + data.location.lng);
      } else {
        alert('not found');
      }
    }
  });
```

Here's the `curl` equivalent:

```
curl -H "Content-Type: application/json" -X POST -d '{"considerIp": true}' https://www.googleapis.com/geolocation/v1/geolocate?key=YOUR-API-KEY
```

Don't forget to swap in a real API key in the examples above AND to [enable the Geolocation API](https://console.developers.google.com/apis/api/geolocation.googleapis.com/overview) for your Google API project.

Comment: Any chance you can provide an html example?

Comment: @RoccoTheTaco: here's [an example](http://jsbin.com/fiberadufu/1/edit?html,console,output) using the same code as above. You will need to set the 'GOOGLE_API_KEY' variable, otherwise this won't work (go to the Google API Console, create a new project, enable the Geolocation API, and get an API key).

Comment: Check the [examples](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/geolocation) in the Google Maps website.

Comment: Isn't this dangerous, since you put your API key in the front-end?

Comment: @Wiezalditzijn that kind of API key is not private and is meant to be read / used in the frontend. you can restrict how/where it's used though which is a good practice -- see [here](https://cloud.google.com/blog/products/maps-platform/google-maps-platform-best-practices-restricting-api-keys) for docs.