# How can i get the current city name in android?

Tags: android, gps, maps

I need to get the user current city name. 
If getting the city name with AGPS or anything is good.
I need the method or code for getting the current city in android.
Please share if you know.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to get city name from latitude and longitude coordinates in Google Maps?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2296377/how-to-get-city-name-from-latitude-and-longitude-coordinates-in-google-maps)

Answer (score 22, accepted):

This one is for getting location name from current lat,long

```
Geocoder gcd = new Geocoder(context, Locale.getDefault());
List<Address> addresses = gcd.getFromLocation(lat, lng, 1);
if (addresses.size() > 0) 
    System.out.println(addresses.get(0).getLocality());
```

Comment: I tried with you code its not working. i have added internet permission and access fine location permission. do i need to add any more permissions.

Comment: try{  
  Geocoder gcd = new Geocoder(context, Locale.getDefault());
  List<Address> addresses = gcd.getFromLocation(16.045813,76.992188, 1);
  
  if (addresses.size() > 0) 
   strlocation = String.valueOf(addresses.get(0).getLocality());
  Toast.makeText(this, strlocation, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
 }catch(Exception e)
 {
  e.printStackTrace();
 }

Comment: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.andro.loc.LocfinderActivity in loader dalvik.system.PathClassLoader[/data/app/com.andro.loc-2.apk]

Comment: Its your activity class not found in DVM. its not a geocoder exception, Have you mentioned activity name in manifest file. if yes then remove application from emulator and re-install it and if not then just add it in manifest.

Comment: I am getting error which says "Timed out waiting for response from server". I have added Internet permission. Do it need something else?

Answer (score 0):

I've upvoted `user370305` answer but i'll just post an alternative just in case.

You can also find the City name from your IP Address.

Check [this site](http://freegeoip.appspot.com/) and this answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3232516/geocode-an-ip-address/3232595#3232595)

Comment: Wats the relevance of IP Address for Mobile android devices?