# free geolocation ip service for java code

Tags: java, ip-geolocation

I hav a java application, and I need location info. based on a given IP. Currently, I'm using http://freegeoip.net. I'm using java, and what I do is get the geolocation information for the mentioned site in csv format, then parse the csv file and locate the country details & display it in my Java application.

Unfortunately, the main problem with this site is that it restricts me to limited the number of queries while I need unlimited queries for educational purposes. can any body provide me with reliable, accurate (as possible), free, unlimited gelocation ip service, in addition to the possibility of giving me the info. in csv format (or any suitable format that I can extract the info. from it to my Java application).

Comment: refer -- http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2083598/google-maps-api-v3-ip-based-geolocation

Comment: freegeoip allows you 1000 queries per hour. Are you sure this is educational purposes?

Comment: Author of freegeoip.net here. The server software and scrips to build the database are all free and open source, and available at https://github.com/fiorix/freegeoip so you can download and run your own, without any limits.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try http://www.maxmind.com/, their database of IP info provides both geo location for free at a city level (you can pay more for more detailed location. There is a java API and the database is stored locally.

Note, this (or any IP lookup) will not work with people connected to corporate VPN - you will get location of their corporate network endpoint.